# Tree Sort Performance

Tags: performance, sorting, data-structures, avl-tree

I have an AVL tree implementation where the insertion method runs in O(log n) time and the method that returns an in-order list representation runs in O(n^2) time. If I have a list needed to be sorted. By using a for-loop, I can iterate through the list and insert each element into the AVL tree, which will run in O(n log n) time combined. So what is the performance of this entire sorting algorithm (i.e. iterate through the list, insert each element, then use in-order traversal to return a sorted list)?

Answer (score 0):

You correctly say that adding n elements to the tree will take time O(nlog(n)). A simple in-order traversal of a BST can be performed in time O(n). It is thus possible to get a sorted list of the elements in time O(nlog(n) + n) = O(nlog(n)). If the time complexity of your algorithm to generate the sorted list from the tree is quadratic (i.e. in O(n^2) but not always in O(n)) the worst case time complexity of the procedure you describe is in O(nlog(n) + n^2) = O(n^2), which is not optimal.